# Execute postgres query in a parse tree form

Tags: postgresql, abstract-syntax-tree

How would one execute a postgresql query's AST directly, without deparsing it first?

Let's say that I parse a query using [libpg_query](https://github.com/lfittl/libpg_query) (or using some of it's wrapper libraries like [pg_query](https://github.com/lfittl/pg_query)).

```
"SELECT 1"
```

becomes

```
[{"SelectStmt": {"targetList": [{"ResTarget": {"val": {"A_Const": {"val": {"Integer": {"ival": 1}}, "location": 7}}, "location": 7}}], "op": 0}}]
```

I would want to directly use the query AST and execute it in a postgres server.

I tried to figure it out by reading postgres source code, but it's a bit over my skill set.

Comment: I don't think you can. Postgres itself only accepts text input, not raw data structures (in what serialisation format, anyway?).